# When I set a background image for UL why do I have to set width and height when child elements already have these set?

Tags: css, height, width, background-image, html-lists

I'm following this tutorial on creating buttons with CSS.
http://www.secondpicture.com/tutorials/web_design/css_ul_li_horizontal_css_menu.html

The background for the buttons is set in the UL element.  What I've noticed is if I remove the height and width attributes of the UL element the background image disappears as if the UL size goes to zero.  This doesn't make sense to me from a box model perspective.  The children elements( LI ) have set dimensions and should be stretching out the size of the UL accordingly.  Can someone explain what is going on?

```
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-image: url(navi_bg.png);
    height: 80px;
    width: 663px;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tutorial, the LIs are float: left, which causes them to no longer take up space in the parent element (UL).  You need a clearfix to resolve this issue, see this thread: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 2):

The `<li>`s are floated so they are removed from the document flow which is causing the `<ul>` to collapse.

To behave like you expect, try adding `float: left;` to the `<ul>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

A good fix that I always use is putting the `<ul>` in a `<div>` as such `<div id="nav"><ul>...</ul></div>` and then applying the background image to the `<div>` element.

Better answer:

In your CSS add `display: table-row;` to the `ul` element and `display: table-cell;` to the `li` elements. This is better than `float: left` since it doesn't collapse your parent element and `display: inline-block` since it doesn't present that annoying gap between items.

Comment: I tried this as well.  There were similar problems.  Seems like a generally good way of approaching things though.